# How can I convert from int to hex

Tags: go, casting

I want to convert from int to hex in Golang.
In strconv, there is a method that converts strings to hex. Is there a similar method to get a hex string from an int?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Since hex is a [Integer literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_literals), you can ask the [fmt package](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) for a string representation of that integer, using [`fmt.Sprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf), and the `%x` or `%X` format.
[See playground](http://play.golang.org/p/GXleKw0OiF)

```
i := 255
h := fmt.Sprintf("%x", i)
fmt.Printf("Hex conv of '%d' is '%s'\n", i, h)
h = fmt.Sprintf("%X", i)
fmt.Printf("HEX conv of '%d' is '%s'\n", i, h)
```

Output:

```
Hex conv of '255' is 'ff'
HEX conv of '255' is 'FF'
```

Answer (score 45):

"Hex" isn't a real thing. You can use a hexadecimal representation of a number, but there's no difference between `0xFF` and `255`. More info on that [can be found in the docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_literals) which point out you can use `0xff` to define an integer constant `255`! As you mention, if you're trying to find the hexadecimal representation of an integer you could use `strconv`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(strconv.FormatInt(255, 16))
    // gives "ff"
}
```

[Try it in the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/T_QR5grpDU)

Comment: This solution does not support the leading zeros though, isn't it? A pity because it's really straightforward.

Comment: @bio you're right, but other solutions on this (four year old question) do support leading zeroes

Answer (score 28):

If formatting some bytes, hex needs a 2 digits representation, with leading 0.

For exemple: 1 => '01', 15 => '0f', etc.

It is possible to force Sprintf to respect this :

```
h:= fmt.Sprintf("%02x", 14)
fmt.Println(h) // 0e
h2:= fmt.Sprintf("%02x", 231)
fmt.Println(h2) // e7
```

The pattern "%02x" means:

- '0' force using zeros
- '2' set the output size as two charactes
- 'x' to convert in hexadecimal

Answer (score 3):

```
i := 4357640193405743614
h := fmt.Sprintf("%016x",i)
fmt.Printf("Decimal: %d,\nHexa: %s", i, h)

# Result
Decimal..: 4357640193405743614,
Hexa.....: 3c7972ab0ae9f1fe
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ndlMyBdQjmT

Answer (score 2):

Sprintf is more versatile but FormatInt is faster. Choose what is better for you

```
func Benchmark_sprintf(b *testing.B) { // 83.8 ns/op
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        _ = fmt.Sprintf("%x", n)
    }
}
func Benchmark_formatint(b *testing.B) { // 28.5 ns/op
    bn := int64(b.N)
    for n := int64(0); n < bn; n++ {
        _ = strconv.FormatInt(n, 16)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

E.g. if its uint32, you can convert it to HEX as seen below =>

```
    var p uint32
    p = 4278190335
    r := p >> 24 & 0xFF
    g := p >> 16 & 0xFF
    b := p >> 8 & 0xFF
    fmt.Println(r, g, b)//255 0 0
```

[DEMO](https://play.golang.org/p/zXL0yAeND56)

you can also check this online tool for ref. https://cryptii.com/pipes/integer-encoder