# How to convert integer to fixed length hex string in Go?

Tags: string, go, type-conversion, int, hex

I want to convert an integer to a hex string with a fixed length of 64 characters, prepended with zeros for integer values that do not use up all 32 hex values. If I try the following it adds spaces in front of `s` rather than zeros.

```
i := 898757
s := fmt.Sprintf("%64x", i)
fmt.Println(s)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert from int to hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581426/how-can-i-convert-from-int-to-hex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct format is `"%064x"`:

```
fmt.Printf("%064x\n", 898757)
```

> 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000db6c5

Where the leading `0` is a "flag" for the formatting string. Per the [fmt docs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing):

> 0:    pad with leading zeros rather than spaces;
>       for numbers, this moves the padding after the sign

My personal preference is to use a period to separate the flags from the length field. This technically works because `.` is not meaningful with the integer verbs and is ignored. I find it a useful visual indicator. The format string becomes `"%0.64x"`.

Comment: Works the same without the dot.

Comment: Thanks @AntonMatveiev, I've clarified the answer.

Comment: I didn't know that the dot is completely ignored, thanks! It looks clearer with the dot.